# Will add-ons from Blender 2.79 work or be compatible with Blender 2.8?

Tags: add-on, versions

The add-ons I use are part of my workflow so I'd like to know if I'll still be able to use them with Blender 2.8.

But if nobody is sure, is there a way i can find out?

Comment: can you edit your question to be more specific. Like do you use external add-ons, if you do can you list some of them, or are these add-ons the default one. and there is no better way to see if they work, then to download the newest version of blender and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, most 2.7# addons will not be compatible with 2.8# versions of Blender, and will require [explicit porting and updating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mjy-zGG3Wk4).

The Python API has changed in ways that break compatibility. It has been improved and expanded to allow further integration, more features, and better workflows and these would make old addons not work in newer versions.

There is a Blender Wiki article documenting the new [Python API changes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API) and explaining how to [port old addons](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons).

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes

**All the addons that come with Blender**, and that still make sense to have (e.g. not the Layer Management addon because Layers don't exist anymore), are planned to be updated and made available in the stable 2.80 release.

#### Maybe

As for the **addons that you might have downloaded from somewhere else**, the best person to ask is the developer/developing house: check on their websites, twitter, github or gumroad: have they announced their plans?